# How to Create an Instance of a Class in runtime derived from ObservableCollection<T>?

Tags: c#, oop, object, instance, observablecollection

How to Create an Instance of a Class in runtime derived from ObservableCollection

The View Model and Model is given below :- C# Coding

```
public class Mobile
{
    ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> SourceCollection = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>();

    private void CreateObject(ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> Source)
    {
        /// Create an Object for MobileModelInfo Class in Runtime and add the Values
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> CostructMobileModel()
    {
        SourceCollection.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "iPhone 4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2011" });
        SourceCollection.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S6", Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone", Year = "2015" });

        CreateObject(SourceCollection);

        return SourceCollection;
    }

}

public class MobileModelInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Catagory { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Everything you're doing is wrong.  Stop.  Get a book.  Read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the Solution for this issue. The Following is the C# Function it Create an Instance of a Class in runtime derived from ObservableCollection

```
private void CreateObject(ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> Source)
{
    var gType = Source.GetType();
    string collectionFullName = gType.FullName;
    Type[] genericTypes = gType.GetGenericArguments();
    string className = genericTypes[0].Name;
    string classFullName = genericTypes[0].FullName;

    // Get the type contained in the name string
    Type type = Type.GetType(classFullName, true);

    // create an instance of that type
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    // List of Propery for the above created instance of a dynamic class
    List<PropertyInfo> oProperty = instance.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the example you've given you don't need a backing variable of `ObservableCollection` type; just inherit from it and your `Mobile` class becomes an observable collection of `MobileModelInfo`s. Note: it's much easier to bind to it using the below design pattern.

```
public class Mobile : ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>
{
    public Mobile()
    {
        Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "foo", Category = "boo", Year = 1988 } );
    }

    public Mobile GetList()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```